# Magento Bundle Product Custom Price Calculation

Tags: php, magento, attributes, bundle, product

I'm stucking on a problem with magentos bundle product prices. After hours of searching and trying I hope someone can help me out with this:

I have bundle products with a base Price (ie: 25,- EUR) - this price is related to 1 Liter.

The Options (simple products) have a base price too (ie: 2,- EUR) and a attribute called "fill_quantity". Here goes a Value like 250ml (0,250).

The calculation (the final price in frontend) should be:

**Bundle Product Base Price *  Attribute Value fill_quantity + Option Base Price**

**iE: 25 * 0,25 + 2 = 8,25 EUR (final Price)**

Thanks and regards
Andi

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check this extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/xlspricecalculator.html

it's able to calculate the final price using excel formulas, combining your product data and user options selected, so you should be able to build such dynamic prices.